# How to match render :status => 412, :error => "Invalid App Key"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

```
if !@app_key
   # throw error here for unknown app
   Rails.logger.error { "Invalid APP Key provided #{app_key}" }
   render :status => 412, :error => "Invalid App Key", :nothing => true
end
```

How can match render :status => 412, :error => "Invalid App Key"

Comment: What do you mean "match" them?

Comment: match to get desire result and check correct run the test.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
response.status.should eq(412)
flash[:error].should eq("Invalid App Key")
```